# Parse the Static URL and Mask the Parameters Values apex

Tags: apex

I Would like to parse the static URL in Apex.

I am looking for a method that can take the URL string as a parameter and Mask the "Parameter values" of the given URL.

Example URL Format

```
URL:`https://goggle.ca?firstName=papa&lastName=john&birthDt=1945-06-01'`
```

Sample code :

```
static string sanitizeUrl(String url) {
        String returnStr ;
        Set<String> strSet = new Set<String>{'firstName', 'lastName'};
        for(String key : strSet) {
            system.debug(url.param(key));
        if(!String.isBlank(url.param(key))) 
         returnStr = returnStr.replaceAll(url.param(key),'Strip it');
        }
        return returnStr;
    }
```

I have gone through the Salesforce Documentation :
[Salesforce Documentation :URL Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_url.htm)

But I couldn't use the methods on the static URL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to battery.cord's excellent answer, I suspect you're actually looking to sanitize all parameters, so you might want a method like this:

```
static String sanitizeUrl(String urlString, String mask) {
  ApexPages.PageReference ref = new ApexPages.PageReference(urlString);
  Map<String, String> params = ref.getParameters();
  for(String key: params.keySet()) {
    params.put(key, mask);
  }
  return ref.getUrl();
}
```

If it's a list of parameters to redact:

```
static String sanitizeUrl(String urlString, String mask, Set<String> maskedParams) {
  ApexPages.PageReference ref = new ApexPages.PageReference(urlString);
  Map<String, String> params = ref.getParameters();
  for(String key: params.keySet()) {
    if(maskedParams.contains(key)) {
      params.put(key, mask);
    }
  }
  return ref.getUrl();
}
```

Other variations are also possible, depending on your intent; the main point is to use PageReference to get the values from the query string, manipulate them, and then return the modified URL.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use `param` or other methods from `PageReference` or `Url` on this variable, because its actually a `String`. You can only use `String` methods on it.

You'll need to create a `PageReference` from the `String` passed to your function. Its really simple, you just pass the string over to the constructor.

You'll need to use `getParameters().get()` instead of `param()` (since thats not a method). You've got a few other issues (such as never defining a value for `returnStr`, but you try to set it to its own value, after calling a replace on it - this'll fail with a null ref), but I see what you're trying to do. I don't think replacing the key names will work - Maps have to have unique names, and it looks like you're just replacing the key, but leaving the value - creating an illegal url/illegal map in code.

My version below just removes the key and the value from the parameter map, if the key is in the url.

Heres a rewrite of your code, without the issues above. You can run this in the developer console to verify the result is as expected (including before/after formatting examples is really helpful for answerers - im guessing this is the format you're looking for, but Im unsure):

```
static string sanitizeUrl(String input) {
    PageReference url = new PageReference(input);

    Set<String> keysToRemove = new Set<String>{'firstName', 'lastName'};

        // See @sfdcfox's comment 
        /**for(String key:keysToRemove) {
            // Remove key & value 
            if (url.getParameters().containsKey(key)) {
                url.getParameters().remove(key);
            }
        }**/

    url.getParameters().keySet().removeAll(keysToRemove);

    return url.getUrl(); 
}

String result = sanitizeUrl('https://goggle.ca?firstName=papa&lastName=john&birthDt=1945-06-01');
String expectedResult = 'https://goggle.ca?birthDt=1945-06-01';

System.assertEquals(expectedResult, result); // true
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: calling remove on a key that doesn't exist doesn't throw an exception, so really no need to check for it first. Also, there's actually a nifty trick I learned ages ago: `url.getParameters().keySet().removeAll(keysToRemove);` is actually a one-liner that doesn't require a for loop at all.

Comment: Thats real nifty! Ill be sure to use that going forward. Making an edit to the code now.