# Parsing the Static URL with ApexPages.Pagereference

Tags: apex

Based on [this question and answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/223392/parse-the-static-url-and-mask-the-parameters-values-apex), I am using the following method to parse the URL:

```
 static String sanitizeUrl(String urlString, String mask) {
      ApexPages.PageReference ref = new ApexPages.PageReference(urlString);
      Map<String, String> params = ref.getParameters();
      if(!params.isEmpty()){
      for(String key: params.keySet()) {
        params.put(key, mask);
      }
      return ref.getUrl();
}
    }
```

I am calling the method :

```
String processEndpoint='https://goggle.ca?firstName=papa&lastName=john';
    Endpoint = Log.sanitizeUrl(processEndpoint,'masked');
```

I have already checked for Map Empty also

but i am getting **"System.NullPointerException: Argument 1 cannot be null"** while running the test class.

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: have you set a PageReference using Test.setCurrentPageReference( pageRef ) ?

Comment: There's no need to `if(!params.isEmpty()) {`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built this in sample and got no errors - would it be possible that there is another error in your test code that is causing this error?

```
public class Log {

   public static String sanitizeUrl(String urlString, String mask) {
        ApexPages.PageReference ref = new ApexPages.PageReference(urlString);
        Map<String, String> params = ref.getParameters();
        if(!params.isEmpty()){
        for(String key: params.keySet()) {
          params.put(key, mask);
        }
      }
      return ref.getUrl();
  }

}
```

Test Class

```
@IsTest
public class LogTest {

    static testMethod void TestLog(){
        String processEndpoint='https://goggle.ca?firstName=papa&lastName=john';
        String endpoint = Log.sanitizeUrl(processEndpoint,'masked');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ronnie ,I have figured out the issue. the URL  string is  blank and the exception is thrown.i have fixed it. Thanks for your time

Comment: great! Happy to help!